# Heroku worker skips Resque's queue configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, resque

In my Procfile I'm defining a worker like:

```
signup_worker: env QUEUE=signups bundle exec rake resque:work
login_worker: env QUEUE=logins bundle exec rake resque:work
```

but after deploy my code, my signup worker keeps processing both signups and logins.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is that possible to do on Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to pass an environment variable to your worker process, but you're using the wrong syntax.

Update your `Procfile` to look like this:

```
signup_worker: QUEUE=signups bundle exec rake resque:work
login_worker: QUEUE=logins bundle exec rake resque:work
```

If you want to pass an environment variable to a process inline, you need to do it in the form `VARIABLE=value <command>`.

I tested this out myself on a dyno just now, and it works great!

Comment: Made what you said but still. My first worker gets the second one messages and vice-versa.

Comment: Are you sure you're properly parsing the environment variables? If you modify your worker code and have it output the `QUEUE` environment variable, you'll see that it will indeed have the correct value. If this is the case, you might have another underlying issue with your resque setup that is not related to the bug in environment variables.

Comment: Thank you very much. You opened my mind about other problems other than my Procfile. I had a resque:setup  on my Rakefile with the following value: QUEUE='*'.